# HOW TO DEAL WITH THESE ERROR ,PL/SQL Compilation unit analysis terminated & PSL-00201 : 'TABLE NAME' MUST BE DECLARED

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a function in Oracle but it's not getting compiled   and I am getting two errors

Error 1.

> Error: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated

Error 2.

> Error(2,16): PLS-00201: identifier 'DIV_DUR_PRICE_TABLE' must be
> declared

**HERE IS THE CODE**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DIV_DAR(FID IN VARCHAR, DATE1 IN DATE, DATE2 IN DATE)   
 RETURN DIV_DUR_PRICE_TABLE PARALLEL_ENABLE AS  
 PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;  
    CNT NUMBER;  
    V_RET DIV_DUR_PRICE_TABLE;  
BEGIN;  
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE from GTT_DIV_DUR_PRICE_TABLE';  

Insert Into GTT_DIV_DUR_PRICE_TABLE 
(select mydate, column1, column2, 0 as Final_value from tablename)

-- please refer my previous question to understand the code written ahead
declare
  v_num integer := 1;
  v_column1 number(8,2);
  v_column2 number(8,2);
  v_Final_value number(8,2);
  begin
  for rec in (select * from GTT_DIV_DUR_PRICE_TABLE order by mydate)
  loop
  if(v_num = 1) then
   
   update tab set Final_value = column1 where mydate = rec.mydate;     
  else
     if(rec.column2 is not null) then
      update tab set Final_value =
       v_Final_value * (v_column1/rec.column1) +
       rec.column2 * (v_column1/v_Final_value) where mydate = rec.mydate;
   else
      update tab set Final_value =
      v_Final_value * (rec.column1 / v_column1) where mydate = rec.mydate;
   end if;
end if;

v_num:= v_num +1;
v_column1 := rec.column1;
v_column2 := rec.column2;

select final_value into v_Final_value from GTT_DIV_DUR_PRICE_TABLE 
where mydate = rec.mydate;
 
end loop;
end;

SELECT 
            CAST(
                MULTISET(

                            SELECT * FROM GTT_DIV_DUR_PRICE_TABLE order by P_DATE desc

                         )AS DIV_DUR_PRICE_TABLE
                ) INTO V_RET FROM DUAL;


        COMMIT;      
RETURN V_RET;
END DIV_DAR;
```

Comment: The error indicates the object DIV_DUR_PRICE_TABLE cannot be found in the current schema.

Comment: yo may need to grant to access that object

Comment: It appears to be a collection type - are you sure it's defined in this schema? (And why is your GTT delete using dynamic SQL?)

Comment: This is the first function I am writing in oracle, so unaware of the procedures to follow. please help me or show me the way which would help me to understand the root problem. @AlexPoole

Comment: How to resolve it @KoenLostrie

Comment: _:How to resolve it:_     see earlier reply by @AliFidanli - "yo may need to grant to access that object "   The key word there is GRANT.  You can look that up in the SQL Language Reference - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/index.html